# how to limit closest() to traverse only one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table on which if I click any row it is supposed to return the row "id" number.I have used closest() function.But the issue is the closest() selects all the "tr" below it. Is there any way to limit the function to traverse only one row data.

For example my table

```
  <tr id="0">
       <td>data0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
       <td>data1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="2">
       <td>data2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="3">
       <td>data3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="4">
       <td>data4</td>
     </tr>
```

If I click the third row that is id=2, it should return only that individual id and td(data2).
This is the code that I am trying as for now.

```
  $("#myTable tr").click(function(){
        trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
        alert(trid);

        return trid;

  });
```

I have tried using next() or find() but I end up getting the Undefined error.Thanks.

Comment: `trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); ` change to `trid = this.id`.

Comment: Jai has right.. You are trying to search `tr` element which is descendant of other `tr` element, but couldn't find it and return `undefined`. sry for my english

Answer (score 4):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of `.closest()`. It traverses up to the parents upward, while `.find()` traverses downwards to the *children/grandchildren*.

So as per your code it seems that you want to have the id of the clicked element. then you can just do this:

```
trid = this.id;
```

as in your code `this` refers to the `tr` you are clicking on.

---

### Note:

Just noticed that you are using a global `var` named `trid` because it does not have the `var` keyword. So if you have accidently used it then you can add `var trid` like this in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {
  var result = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="0">
       <td>data0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
       <td>data1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="2">
       <td>data2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="3">
       <td>data3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="4">
       <td>data4</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
 $("#myTable tr").click(function(){
        trid = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(trid);
        //if you want to get to the td of it
        var tdVal = $(this).find('td').html();
  });
```

Comment: Hi Hoja I did try the code but it still comes up the same.If I had 4 rows and I click the third row the id is coming up correct but the alert displays twice for third and fourth row.

Comment: Hi Sorry Please ignore the above comment.It is working correctly in case of updating the table through id. Thanks for the help.

Comment: also in jquery it's better to bind the event on body. Because it'll also works on dynamic elements. 
for eg:
------- 
  $("body).on('click','#myTable tr',function(){

Answer (score 0):

by clicking on `tr`, you do not need to use `.closest()` to access its id, just get its id using the `.attr('id')`or `.prop('id')` or even simply `.id`  as follows:

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function(){
        trid = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(trid);    
});
```